# parsing nexted json in databricks delta live tables

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

1st Question => Can we parse a nested JSON through SQL notebook and load the same in a delta live table ?

2nd Question => I am able to parse nested JSON using python notebook and able to print that. But can I load the data in a delta live table from there?

Comment: Please provide more information about your data (is it single line or multi-line), and how do you parse data using Python

Answer (score 0):

> Can we parse a nested JSON through SQL notebook and load the same in a
> delta live table?

You can parse a nested JSON in a SQL notebook in Databricks Delta and load the data into a Delta live table, by using the built-in JSON functions in SQL. You can use the `from_json` to parse the nested JSON data and then use the `INSERT INTO` to load the data into a Delta live table.

> I am able to parse nested JSON using python notebook and able to print
> that. But can I load the data in a delta live table from there?

Yes, you can load the data parsed from a nested JSON in a Python notebook into a Delta live table, by first parsing the JSON (using Python's `json` module or pandas), then creating a `DataFrame` using the parsed data and then use the `write` method of the `DataFrame` to write the data to a Delta live table.